# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Qual problema com meu código, no console mostra este erro:

```
home:85 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
        at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (home:85)
        at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
        at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
```

Pesquisando [encontrei isso no SoEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991919/jquery-3-slim-ajax-basic-example):

Meu código *javascript*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault(), $('#btn-login').html('Autenticando...');

              var username = $('#username').val();

              if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$/.test(username)) {
                $('.form-message').css('display', 'block'),
                $('.message').html('Existem caracteres especiais no seu usuário. Se estiver usando <strong>"@"</strong>, remova-o!');

                return false;
              }

              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(s) {
                  alert('ok');
                }
              });
            });
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: qual versão do jquery está usando?

Comment: Ja arrumei companheiro, valeu. a versão está ali em cima, `jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js`

Comment: Na verdade não era a intenção porém eu consegui arrumar e coloquei a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rapaziadas, encontrei o erro nesta linha:

```
if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$/.test(username))
```

Troquei por

```
if (0 == /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$/.test(username))
```

Lembrando a versão `slim` do `jquery` não possui `$.ajax({})`

[Referência](https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/20/jquery-3-2-1-now-available/)

> Sometimes you don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many
>   standalone libraries that focus on ajax requests. And often it is
>   simpler to use a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all
>   your web animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that
>   includes the ajax and effects modules, we’ve released a “slim” version
>   that excludes these modules. The size of jQuery is very rarely a load
>   performance concern these days, but the slim build is about 6k gzipped
>   bytes smaller than the regular version – 23.6k vs 30k. These files are
>   also available in the npm package and on the CDN:

Comment: Boa dica no 'slim' do jquery não possuir $.ajax({}) !!